# Task scheduler-run on event for a specific task only

Tags: windows, powershell, taskscheduler

I have a powershell script which triggers an email and I have saved this as `EmailScript.PS1` (*no issues with the script,it runs just fine*). I am planning to schedule this script whenever an event is logged in ,example:

```
Event ID:111    Description:Task terminated
```

I am successfully able to schedule this script whenever the required event is triggered.

However, currently it takes into account all the tasks (not my target task named `xyz` for example) which is running in task scheduler.

I would like to schedule this event based task only when an event is triggered for a specific task(not all the tasks), but couldnot find such a filter/dropdown in the task scheduler create task tab.

Any suggestions/help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend using the custom XML event filter to do this, as it gives you a bit more flexibility to select what kind of events to trigger on.

To do this, do the following:

- Go the Triggers tab and click new / edit the trigger.
- On **Begin the task** section change the type to On An Event.
- Click custom option under the Settings section.
- Click the Edit Event Filter... button.
- Go the XML tab and at the bottom of the menu press the edit query manually button.
- Copy and paste the below XML and OK the changes.

Note: Make sure to replace the **TASK_NAME_HERE** with the name of the task you want to trigger on. Additionally, you can replace **TaskSuccessEvent** with a different event name if you want to trigger on a different event type.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">*[EventData[@Name='TaskSuccessEvent'][Data[@Name='TaskName']='\TASK_NAME_HERE']]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Edit: To match multiple event IDs of a specific task, you can do the following:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
        *[EventData[Data[@Name='TaskName']='\TASK_NAME_HERE']]
        and
        *[System[(EventID='102' or EventID='103')]]
        </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

For additional reading, see the following: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/09/26/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer/

Comment: I've added an explanation for matching to multiple event IDs and further reading on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

You could query the event log for the latest instance of the `111` event id and grab the task name from there:

```
$event = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Id=111;LogName='Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational'} -MaxEvents 1
$taskName = $event.Properties[0].Value

if($taskName -ne '\xyz'){
    # not the right task, abort
    exit
}
```